# Can't open video by OpenCv ErrorUnhandled exception at 0x7695c41f in moving movie.exe:

Tags: opencv, video

I write a very simple program to test to open a video by openCV, but I fail.

Here is the code.

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" 
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" 

 using namespace cv ;

 void main( void) {  
 namedWindow( "Example3", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
 VideoCapture cap; 
 cap.open( "D:\a.mp4" ); 
 cv::Mat frame; 

 while( 1 ) { 
    cap >> frame;  
  //cap.read(frame);
  if( !frame.data ) break;            
  cv::imshow( "Example3", frame ); 
  waitKey(33);
  } 
 }
```

It just flash the windows, However, if I comment the if( !frame.data ) break;
  I will get this:
  Unhandled exception at 0x7695c41f in moving movie.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:    cv::Exception at memory location 0x0045f968..

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cap.open( "D:\a.mp4" );` should be:

```
 cap.open( "D:\\a.mp4" );
```

Comment: i believe in windows it's also "//" for a single dash. (or was it "\\"?!)

Comment: Thank you so much， it is the reason. I just paste the path displayed by property of the video. Under windows, the path is "\", so... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your video in the "current directory" so that you can give the path simply as `cap.open( "a.mp4" );`. 
So, your program should look like following:

```
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" 
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" 

 using namespace cv ;

 void main( void) 
 {

 namedWindow( "Example3", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 
 VideoCapture cap; 
 cap.open( "a.mp4" ); 
 cv::Mat frame; 

      while( 1 ) 
      { 
         cap >> frame;  
       //cap.read(frame);
       if( !frame.data ) break;            
       cv::imshow( "Example3", frame ); 
       waitKey(33);

       } 

 }
```

**PS:** I think the way you are giving path for video is also wrong, it should be forward slash `/` not backward which you are using i.e. `\`

Comment: Placing waitKey outside while loop will not display the video.